# Connection issue with Mongo database using Intellij and Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, containers

I have a Mongo database running through Docker but I am unable to connect to it using `Intellij`.

(I am getting a timeout).

Can you help me?

```
Error: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information"
```

Thx

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: PanDiMooN
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: PanDiMooN
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: The_Milky_Way
```

[image: Docker]
[image: Docker]

[image: Timeout err]

I tried to restart the container, change ports but I am still getting the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ is trying to connect to `localhost` on port `27017`. `localhost` is how your computer refers to itself in networks. The problem is that your computer isn't listening for requests on this port, a Docker container on your computer is.

To bind requests to port `27017` with your Docker container, you can add a [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) section to the compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: PanDiMooN
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: PanDiMooN
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: The_Milky_Way
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```